# C# Dynamically reference objects in loop

Tags: c#, variables, parameters, loops

I don't know whether this is possible or not. What I want to do is to reference a DataTable (and other objects, but getting it working for one will make the rest easy) and use it as a paramater, but I want to do this in a loop, so that I can perform the function with each DataTable dt1, dt2, dt3 etc. Something like this (although this obviously doesn't work):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++)
{
    Load("dt"+i);
}
```

Is this actually possible to do?

Comment: Where are your `DataTable`s stored?  Do you have a separate variable for each named, dt1, dt2, etc or are they stored in something like a hastable where the stirngs dt1, dt2, etc are the keys?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stick all your `DataTable`s into an array:

```
var dataTables = new[] { dt1, dt2, dt3 };
foreach(var dt in dataTables)
    // ...
```

Comment: jeez, its so obvious now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the method sugested by Anton Gogolev.  However you can do it how you want using the '[System.Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.aspx)' namespace.  Here is an example.  Notice that the `DataTable` members must be `public` for the `GetField` to work.

```
public DataTable dt0 = new DataTable();
public DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
public DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

public void findall()
{
    DataTable temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        temp = (DataTable)this.GetType().GetField("dt" + i.ToString()).GetValue(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to do.  If you can reference them at compile time you can stick them in an array like Anton said.  Otherwise you have to use Reflection to work with them.  Either way, the DataTable instances have to be stored in some variable somewhere.  Can you give a bit more context?  Where are the DataTables coming from?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach( var dt in new List<int>() { dt1,dt2,dt3,dt4,dt5 })
{
 // do something   
}
```